# With jQuery how to check dynamically inserted class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an LI which I'm adding classes to dynamically.

I need to check if the LI has a certain class that was inserted dynamically and insert another class into it.

How is is this possible?

More explanation: After DOM loads the LI looks like this:

```
<li class="active"></li>
```

After dynamically inserting a class the LI looks like this:

```
<li class="active correct"></li>
```

Now I need to check if the LI contains the class "correct"

Comment: $(selector).hasClass("class")

Comment: @Dimitri I tried that, it only checks after the DOM loads initially, not after the class was inserted dynamically.

Comment: Sorry but the question still seems a little unclear. When are you adding the class? It sounds like your looking for some event that fires when a new class is added/removed if I understand correctly. Unfortunately I do not think there is such a thing.

Comment: you have to check after it gets added.

Comment: @Richard, shouldn't matter when you insert class. hasClass will always check current state at the time of invocation. May be your invocation is not timed right. Please show some more code.

Comment: @Dimitri ok thanks for that, I'll have to recheck the code then.

Comment: Have you tried `window.onload` instead of `document.ready`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.hasClass()` to check whether the selected element is having a particular class or not.
It doesn't matter when you are adding those classes. Dynamically added classes would also deliver same result with `.hasClass()`.

Try,

```
$('li').hasClass('correct')
```

Comment: I tried, and it only works after the initial DOM load, it doesn't work afterwards.

Comment: @Richard what are you doing after the DOM got loaded.?